# How to fit / displayed the remote image URL into webview Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: webview, titanium, imageurl

I am trying to display a remote image url into webview in both iPhone & Android using Appcelerator Titanium. The remote image is displayed in webview but the full image doesn't fit into the webview in app.

Code:

```
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        url : 'https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/dhl5ctlq1/image/upload/v1364796700/business_logo_4_53_1364308382.jpg',
        top : 0,
        left : x(60),
        height : '80dp',
        width : '80dp',
        scalesPageToFit : true,
        showScrollbars : false,
        scrollsToTop:false,
        backgroundColor : "red"
    });
```

Comment: 1. Why don't use image view? 2. Try to embed it into a html page instead of loading the image itself. 3. How should it fit for you?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a WebView, a WebView is for displaying web content (read: HTML), instead just use a ImageView, these support remote URL's, just remember that on iOS these remote images are cached, but on Android they are NOT (big oversight on appcelerator's side). Try this instead:

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : 'https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/dhl5ctlq1/image/upload/v1364796700/business_logo_4_53_1364308382.jpg',
        top : 0,
        left : x(60),
        height : '80dp',
        width : '80dp'
        backgroundColor : "red"
    });
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your replay. I am using more then one image in a same window, when ever i am using Ti.UI.createImageView its affect the app performance(The particular screen struck and slow), so i want to overcome that problem by using webview.

Comment: A webview will kill performance a hundred times lot faster than multiple image views. The thing that is probably killing performance is (if you are on android) that the image views are not caching.